# Github API, how to use blobs

Tags: github, blob, github-api

In order to understand how blobs work in Github API, I tried to create a blob with showing in the below poster, I got 201 created in the response, but in my github repository I say nothing about this blob. I don't understand how the blob works here, my expected function of the blob is that it allows me to push a file to the repository, basically what I want to achieve is use github API to push files to the repository, how to do this with the blob API?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> my expected function of the blob is that it allows me to push a file to the repository

Git doesn't ever push files. It pushes *commits*. And Git blobs are pretty low-level.

I think you're using the wrong API endpoint. The [`contents` endpoint lets you create files](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#create-a-file):

> ### Create a file
>
> This method creates a new file in a repository
>
> ```
> PUT /repos/:owner/:repo/contents/:path
> ```
>
> #### Parameters
>
> - path (string, required): The content path
> - message (string, required): The commit message
> - content (string, required): The new file content, Base64 encoded
> - branch (string): the branch name. Default: the repository’s default branch (usually `master`)
>
> #### Optional Parameters
>
> You can provide an additional `committer` parameter, which is an object containing information about the committer. Or, you can provide an `author` parameter, which is an object containing information about the author.

Comment: If I add a new file to my local repository, I need to do `git add, git commit, git push`, then this file exists on the remote, I want to achieve this with github API, is it possible? If so, how to do it. Thank you.

Comment: What should `:path` be when creating a file? I tried `PUT https://api.github.com//repos/me/myrepo/contents/index.html`, the response is not found.

Comment: From [this](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/) site it seems that blob should be the one to use, my scenario is that I generated a html file locally and I want to add this file to the remote repository, but I don't know how to use the blob to achive this.\

Comment: @msn, I'm not sure why you think that page suggests using the `blob` API to create files. It very clearly states that it is for low-level Git functionality: "gives you access to read and write raw Git objects to your Git database". The `:path` should be the relative path to the file. Does the repository exist already?

Comment: I misunderstood the Base64 encoding, now I've successfully creating a file with the API, thank you for your help.